# ANTLR C# How to get specific nodes from the tree?

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, antlr, antlr3

I am parsing text files. I used **ANTLRWorks** to write and check grammars and the **ANTLR3 C# tool** from the *theantlrguy.atlassian.net* to compile grammars.

By this moment I can build the AST and print all nodes to the console (by recursively getting children).
However, I'd like to **get specific nodes** according to my tokens.

**E.g.** I have a node *Parameter* with a child *Name*. The node *Name* in its turn has a child *"Johnny"*.
In my app I'd like to have an object *Parameter* with a field *string Name="Johnny"*.

I've found the **tree grammar** is necessary to get the nodes from the AST, so I've written one. However, I cannot find a way to use it.

Here is my *options* and example (simplified) *Lexer and Parser rules* from the **combined grammar**:

```
options {
language=CSharp3;
TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
output=AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree; }

tokens {
StatementT;
ParameterT;
NameT; }

statement : object -> ^(StatementT object);
object : name -> ^(ParameterT name);
name : NAME -> ^(NameT NAME);
```

Here is the part from the **tree grammar** (options and simplified rules):

```
options {
language=CSharp3;
tokenVocab=myGrammar;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree; }

statement : ^(StatementT object);
object : ^(ParameterT name);
name : ^(NameT NAME);
```

And here is the part of the **source code**:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(inputString);
myGrammarLexer lexer = new myGrammarLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
myGrammarParser parser = new myGrammarParser(tokens);
var result = parser.statement();
CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)result.Tree;
```

As I've searched, there comes the following code to **walk the tree**:

```
CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(tree);
nodes.TokenStream = tokens;
myTreeGrammar walker = new myTreeGrammar(nodes);
walker.statement();
```

This one compiles, but I have no clue where to dig next.

What could you advise?

Comment: Is there are particular reason you are using ANTLR 3? [ANTLR 4](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/releases/latest) makes this task (and nearly everything else) much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was my first experience w/ ANTLR, so I've started w/ ANTLRWorks to see the visual representation. AFAIK the last version of ANTLRWorks is based on the ANTLR3, so that was the reason. Is it time-consuming to switch between ANTLR3 and ANTLR4?

Comment: [ANTLRWorks 2](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/antlrworks) was built for ANTLR 4. Starting earlier this year, the latest releases are now distributed through the [NetBeans Plugin Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53652/antlrworks-2), and through the Update Center (Tools &rarr; Plugins) once they verify the latest release (which was uploaded yesterday).

Comment: Okay, now I think I've rewritten my grammar to the antlr4 requirements. I've done all steps from this [Readme](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/Readme.md). I've taken then "Hello" grammar, I've marked 'generate listener' and 'generate visitor' as true, though I've got no code generated in the HelloLexer and HelloParser classes when I hit 'build'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No generated code is placed in those files. Those files are added to the project as a location where you can add additional code to those classes, without resorting to using an `@parser::members{}` or `@lexer::members{}` block in the grammar. The actual generated files for the parser are placed in **obj/Debug** or **obj/Release**, depending on your current build configuration.

Comment: I guess, I got this. Thanks!